# Show that if the origin is neither an essential singularity, nor a pole of order 2 or higher, then f must be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

A function f: G $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb C$ has period p $\in$ $\Bbb C$ if f(z+p) = f(z) for all z $\in$ G.

Let G = $\Bbb C$ $\setminus$ {m + ni | m, n $\in$ $\Bbb Z$} and suppose f: G $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb C$ is a holomorphic function with periods 1 and i.

Show that if the origin is neither an essential singularity, nor a pole of order 2 or higher, then f must be constant.

I understand an essential singularity means that the power series has negative coefficients, so we are looking for an origin that is nonnegative and there will only be one singularity?

Comment: If $f$ has at most a first order pole at the origin, why must in fact the residue there be $0$? So what does that tell you about $f$?

Comment: Teeing off of @TedShifrin's comment: if a pole of order 1 is a unique case, that means you should probably check residues. Sometimes the answer is in the question.

Comment: You could try asking your professor who assigned this take-home exam problem.

Comment: @JessePeterson this was a mistake after reading the rules and i'm not using it! can't figure out how to delete!